# "foreign key mismatch" in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

im trying to build a database and i had some troubles with my tables when i try to insert.

t_users:

```
CREATE TABLE t_users(
username TEXT primary key not null, 
password TEXT not null,
email TEXT not null);
```

t_games:

```
CREATE TABLE t_games(
game_id integer primary key autoincrement not null,
status integer not null, 
start_time DATETIME not null, 
end_time DATETIME);
```

t_questions:

```
CREATE TABLE t_questions(
question_id integer primary key autoincrement not null,
question TEXT not null, 
correct_ans TEXT not null, 
ans2 TEXT not null, 
ans3 TEXT not null, 
ans4 TEXT not null);
```

t_playeranswers:

```
CREATE TABLE t_players_answers(
game_id integer not null, 
username TEXT not null,
question_id integer not null, 
player_answer TEXT not null, 
is_correct integer not null, 
answer_time integer not null, 
primary key(game_id,username,question_id), 
foreign key(game_id) REFERENCES t_games(game_id), 
foreign key(username) REFERENCES t_users(username), 
foreign key(question_id) REFERENCES t_users(question_id)
);
```

and when i try to insert into t_players_answers table with this line:

```
insert into t_players_answers values(0,'user',2,'the king',1,1);
```

its just doesn't seem to work and its gives me this error:

> SQL error: foreign key mismatch - "t_players_answers" referencing
>   "t_users"

i checked that the 'user' exist in the t_users table and i just can't find the solution..

if you could help me i would be thankful!

Comment: SQLLite is not the same as SQL-Server. This does not look like SQL server.

Comment: And the question has nothing to do with c++ (even if you are using the queries from within c++ code).

Comment: The error tells that there apparently is no such entry existing. Check the table again - and consider case this time. SQL is mostly case-insensitive, however, this does not apply for string comparisons. So if the username actually is 'User', it won't be found if you compare against 'user', no matter if used in a `SELECT` query or when referencing as foreign key.

Comment: first, thanks for the comment.. second, i looked at the users table again and'user' does exist there for sure. any other suggestions?